# Buying a server -- mainly want many DIMM slots and hard drive bays

Tags: hardware

I want to buy a sever that has:

- Many DIMM slots for memory expansion
- Many hard drive bays

What are the best options for this? I don't want service warranties, or anything like that...

Comment: Post actual numbers for DIMM slots and bays, it will help.

Comment: Plus price target and use case.

Comment: Where? This is a global web site and not all products are available in all locations. Also, what is your definition of "many"? Is it 10, 20, 100, what?

Comment: This question really doesn't give enough information to answer it properly; I suggest you rewrite it, including at least some of the following: - Do you want this server to be rack-mounted? - How many memory slots do you actually mean by "many"? - The same as above for disks. - BTW, what kind of disks? SCSI? SATA? SAS? - What about CPU slots? - What's your price range? - Where are you located in this big, big world? Also, having at least an idea of what the server will be actually used for would really help.

Comment: Agreed. Voted to closed based on not enough information.

Answer (score 3):

HP ProLiant DL370 G6 would do the job. Up to 24 drive bays and 18 DIMM slots. Worldwide quickspecs linked here:
http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13242_div/13242_div.html

Answer (score 1):

HP have a server with 128 memory slots out in the next few months.

Answer (score 0):

This question really doesn't give enough information to answer it properly; I suggest you rewrite it, including at least some of the following:

- Do you want this server to be rack-mounted?
- How many memory slots do you actually mean by "many"?
- The same as above for disks.
- BTW, what kind of disks? SCSI? SATA? SAS?
- What about CPU slots?
- What's your price range?
- Where are you located in this big, big world?

Also, having at least an idea of what the server will be actually used for would really help.

Comment: Could you please copy these suggestions as new comment to the question? Thank you! ~ This answer and comment will auto-destruct in 24 hours ;)